# UVCCapture resulting in: ioctl querycontrol error 22

Tags: linux, webcam, capture

I'm trying to capture an image from my webcam (Raspberry Pi, Rasbpbian). Using the following command:

```
uvccapture -v
```

I get the following output:

```
Using videodevice: /dev/video0
Saving images to: snap.jpg
Image size: 320x240
Taking snapshot every 0 seconds
Taking images using mmap
Unable to set format: 22.
 Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal
```

Any suggestions? What exactly is error 22? I didn't have any luck googling it. I tried adding the `-r` flag but instead it then produced the error `/dev/video0 does not support read i/o`.

I've managed to get the webcam to work using `motion` but it's not suitable for my needs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the `-m` switch. It tells the program to use another color format. It worked fine with my camera on my RPi.